# Add DXF text to shape as attribute

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dxf, text

I have a DXF with text and I have a shapefile with some squares.

Is it possible, in QGIS, to add the text from the DXF to a new column in the shapefile?

Answer (score 3):

`DXF` text, so called  `label`  seems to be placed arbitrary on the map. 
But you can find some spatial logic on how they are related to the geometry object. 
If so, you can convert label to point and set the text to your attribute table by using [`dxf2shape` plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_dxf2shape_converter.html).

Then you can perform spatial's relationship between your layers :
`WITHIN`, `INTERSECT`  or any other spatial operator you need.

Then join their attributes to get the `text` value of `label` geometries.

You can also  use  neighbours relationship. 
But keep in mind that it depends to your data and choices made by the dxf drawer when he placed label on the map you get.